# How do you Make Ubuntu One re-authenticate?

Tags: 10.10, ubuntu-one, authentication

I was trying to restart syncing with Ubuntu One because it was not syncing my music folder.  However, I accidently deleted my computer from the sync list:

(Ubuntu One.com > Account > View the machines connected to this account)

So, my question is, how do I re-add my computer to the list?

I am currently running Ubuntu 10.10

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [UbuntuOne FAQ](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/FAQ):

> - Open System->Preferences->Passwords and Encryption Keys
> - Right-click on the entry "Ubuntu One" and select "Delete"
> - Open System->Preferences->Ubuntu One and it should prompt you to re-add the machine

In case you were wondering where the `Ubuntu One` token is, right click on **`Passwords:`**`default` and select unlock. The `Ubuntu One` token is inside that folder.

[image]